# How do I retrieve the resource class from a URL in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am trying to dig the resource class out of a URL. So I have this:

`/users/1/friends`

And I want to extract the `Friend` resource out of that somehow. String matching will work for this example, but I want to use the same algorithm for every route in my application, and they can get complicated.

Is there a Rails helper somewhere that will get take the URL, somehow compare vs routes.rb, and then return the resource that the URL will hit?

I have seen `params[:controller]` before, and I hace the `Rack::Request` object for each of the requests, but it doesn't seem to pick up that parameter.

Comment: I think there is a better approach than extracting the controller name from the URL.  Show us what you are trying to do before parsing the URL, maybe we can think of a better approach.  For example, if you use the resource paths then it will take care of this problem for you.

Comment: I am extracting the resource class from a Rack::Request object. I found `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.url)` which seems to do what I want, unless you have a better way?

Comment: Not really.  Sounds like a good option.  You might want to answer the question and accept it.

Comment: I'd like to leave it open for awhile and see if anyone else has another option :)

Comment: What it seems like you want is, in effect, to replicate the functionality of the Rails router -- match a path to a resource.  So in all likelihood the method you found (`recognize_path`) is the code that does that work.  I am curious what you're trying to accomplish, but concur with @D3mon-1stVFW that the approach you found is good.  If you do answer, it might be helpful to explain in what case this is useful :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using `recognize_path`. Since others have asked, the reason why this was needed because I was writing code to automatically document JSON API's based on Cucumber tests. So when a test is run, I inspect the `last_request` object in a Cucumber `After` block, and from that infer which resource is being accessed so I could group each test by resource.